# Unescape a string in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, encoding, escaping

I have an input which is:
%u05D0%u05DC%20%u05E2%u05DC

When I run the built-in browser function (on the console for example):
`unescape("%u05D0%u05DC%20%u05E2%u05DC")`

The result is: "אל על"

When I run the same thing in NodeJS using the [unescape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unescape) module, the returned string is the same as original.
Also tried to use the querystring.unescape function, but the same result.

Is there a way to imitate the same decoding functionality I got from the browser in a NodeJS application?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the same function `unescape` without installing any module? Btw [unescape](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks! it solved my problem. You can post an answer so that I can mark it fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node doesn't require any specific library to perform basic JavaScript operations. Besides, behind Chrome and Node there is the same JS engine V8. So as I commented you can use directly `unescape`.

Comment: strange, but my PHP Storm suggests to change it, as it is deprecated symbol

Answer (score 1):

You can use `decodeURIComponent` instead of unescape.